# How can I put multiple statements in one line?

Tags: python

I know a little bit of comprehensions in Python, but they seem very hard to 'read'. The way I see it, a comprehension might accomplish the same as the following code:

```
for i in range(10): if i == 9: print('i equals 9')
```

This code is much easier to read than how comprehensions currently work, but I've noticed you can’t have two `:`s in one line. This brings me to:

Is there a way I can get the following example into *one line*?

```
try:
    if sam[0] != 'harry':
        print('hello',  sam)
except:
    pass
```

Something like this would be great:

```
try: if sam[0] != 'harry': print('hellp',  sam)
except:pass
```

But again I encounter the conflicting `:`s.

I'd also love to know if there's a way to run `try` (or something like it) without `except`. It seems entirely pointless that I need to put `except:pass` in there. It’s a wasted line.

Comment: Why would it ever throw an exception?

Comment: sam[2] may not exist. It's a hypothetical example. thanks

Comment: Comprehension is something different in Python. Putting everything in one line is not comprehension.

Comment: I am aware of this yes. thanks. I was just demonstrating how i think comprehension might work better but can't due to the colon which is the root of my problem/question

Comment: Just use `\n`s and use spaces for indents.

Comment: Sidenote, [a bare `except` is bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54948548/4518341), especially where you're not doing anything to handle it.

Comment: Python does support single line see [answer May 29, 2011 at 11:00](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6167353/6345724) ... BUT. 
Most standard code blocks do not support single line. Code author needs to find a `lambda` equivalent. Examples:
`try` alternative(s) `with contextlib.suppress(Exception): {code}` 
`if` alternative(s) `{true code} if {boolean result} else {false code}` (software: Python3)

Comment: Note: [A late answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167127/how-can-i-put-multiple-statements-in-one-line/24451002#24451002) (3 years after), seems to indicate one-liners, ***incl. control structures***, are indeed possible in Python.

Answer (score 192, accepted):

Unfortunately, what you want is not possible with Python (which makes Python close to useless for command-line one-liner programs). Even explicit use of parentheses does not avoid the syntax exception. You can get away with a sequence of simple statements, separated by semicolon:

```
for i in range(10): print "foo"; print "bar"
```

But as soon as you add a construct that introduces an indented block (like `if`), you need the line break. Also,

```
for i in range(10): print "i equals 9" if i==9 else None
```

is legal and might approximate what you want.

If you are still determined to use one-liners, see the answer by [elecprog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24451002/127465).

As for the `try ... except` thing: It would be totally useless **without** the `except`. `try` says "I want to run this code, but it might throw an exception". If you don't care about the exception, leave out the `try`. But as soon as you put it in, you're saying "I want to handle a potential exception". The `pass` then says you wish to not handle it specifically. But that means your code will continue running, which it wouldn't otherwise.

Comment: interesting, i think your latter example comes closest to the answer I was looking for. thanks

Comment: with regards to the 'try' question ... What If, I know at some point it is going to throw an exception but I just want the code to continue running ... for instance, to check if a string can be an integer try: int(string) ... If it can't, then just continue to the next line, no need for an exception. I see what you're saying, but is there any other way that can accommodate for this type of checking/error-handling

Comment: Re ``try:``: The Python syntax rules simply won't let you get away with a sole "try" clause without accompanying "except" clause. What I do is wrapping the try-except in on own function, and call this instead. Like ``if (checkint(s))...`` and ``def checkint(s): try: int(s)\nreturn True\nexcept: return False``.

Comment: ThomasH, I wish your comment were an answer to a question somewhere so I could upvote it. Excellent.

Comment: @ThomasH When you put `pass` in except you _are_ saying you wish to handle the exception specifically -- by doing nothing! `except: pass` is a dangerous design move IMO, as it will probably hide errors one didn't expect. Better to drop the try/except, list specific exceptions you expect, or improve your design and code to avoid errors!

Comment: @ThomasH "*(which makes Python close to useless for command-line one-liner programs)*"  : does not hinder me. 95% cases need no new-line. And the rest via \n                                            :                                 `python -c "exec\"print 'A' \nfor i in 1,2,3: print i \""`

Comment: Downvoted because: No answer to the question plus language bashing.

Comment: @kxr - Not working for me... can't see what I am doing wrong. `python2.7 -c "import ssl\nprint ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION"` gives `SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character`.   I had to do this (which is getting a bit hairy and probably won't render properly in a comment): `python2.7 -c "\`printf 'import ssl\nprint ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION'\`"`

Comment: @ThomasH can i do the second line without else?

Comment: @JoshuaVarghese No, I'm afraid Python's [Conditional Expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) can only be used with the `else` (prob. b/c it's an expression and not a statement).

Comment: When i give the else as None, sometimes values become none. also in one-liners, is it possible to do liner `[i for i in list1 if i not (here in this list]` ???

Comment: @JoshuaVarghese Yes, because the Condtional Expression always returns a value, either from the false or the true case. And yes, you can use List Comprehension in one-liners, but mind that the `if` in a list comprehension is not the `if` of a Conditional Expression. It pertains to the list comprehension syntax itself, and here no `else` is allowed: `python -c "print([i for i in range(10) if i==9])` (using Python3 syntax). You can easily find that out by trying.

Comment: i wanted like if i not in this present list which is being comprehensed

Comment: Mh, you want to avoid duplicates in the result? I'm not sure this is possible, but that's a question on its own, right?! You might want to ask that here on SO.

Comment: @ThomasH it is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61290039/how-to-access-the-current-list-that-is-being-comprehensed

Comment: @ThomasH but it happened as i feared. it got downvoted :(

Comment: @TorstenBronger This does answer the question, and the language bashes itself by not having the capacity. You're shooting the messenger.

Comment: So, alas, python may be one of the few programming languages that are affected by terminal width. Programmer A with a wide terminal might write highly nested great programs, but Programmer B with not so wide a terminal would find they are no longer on an equal playing field...

Comment: A [later answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167127/how-can-i-put-multiple-statements-in-one-line/24451002#24451002) seems to contradict. Perhaps address that in your answer? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today (how this came to be is not of interest to most readers).)

Comment: @PeterMortensen I'm aware of the issues with legacy answers, and would only use "Edit" or "Update" paragraphs when I retain the old answer (e.g. when it still applies to an older version of the software).

Comment: @DanJacobson, "highly nested great programs" is an oxymoron. :-P

Answer (score 77):

You could use the built-in exec statement, eg.:

```
exec("try: \n \t if sam[0] != 'harry': \n \t\t print('hello',  sam) \nexcept: pass")
```

Where `\n` is a newline and `\t` is used as indentation (a tab).
Also, you should count the spaces you use, so your indentation matches exactly.

However, as all the other answers already said, this is of course only to be used when you really **have** to put it on one line.

`exec` is quite a dangerous statement (especially when building a webapp) since it allows execution of arbitrary Python code.

Comment: Thank you! This should be marked as the correct answer, as it actually works, unlike the others. But of course, **never** do this unless you have to! I actually need this syntax however, as I have to input scripts into a fixed one-line text-box.

Comment: Thanks ! Lifesaver !
I don't use this in my script, but in the interactive shell this is useful for debugging...
I often simply quit the interactive shell and restart it to get a clean environment and then I have to repeat certain steps, i.e. importing a module, running some functions and then do some test with a specific function.
Soooo, I was looking for a way to put "importing a module, running some functions" in a oneliner, so I can quickly call it back from the history and run it (instead of having to call back 5 different items from the history) +1

Comment: `exec("try: \n if sam[0] != 'harry': print('hello',  sam) \nexcept: pass")` 

nicer :)

Comment: Thank you kxr :) (I used your idea to improve the answer)

Comment: This is a clever idea. Are the spaces around newlines and tabs necessary? It strikes me as odd that Python does not complain about this whitespace

Comment: They are not necessary, but I added them for clarity. You have to be consistent though, indentation has to match exactly. I don't know what the rules are now (8 years later), mixing tabs and spaces is kinda fragile.

Answer (score 29):

You can now just use semicolons. However, you cannot use if/elif/else statements, for/while loops, and you can't define functions. The main use of this would be when using imported modules where you don't have to define any functions or use any if/elif/else/for/while statements/loops.

Here's an example that takes the artist of a song, the song name, and searches genius for the lyrics:

```
import bs4, requests; song = input('Input artist then song name\n'); print(bs4.BeautifulSoup(requests.get(f'https://genius.com/{song.replace(" ", "-")}-lyrics').text,'html.parser').select('.lyrics')[0].text.strip())
```

Answer (score 12):

I do not incentivise this, but say you're on the command line, you have nothing but Python and you really need a one-liner, you can do this:

```
python -c "$(echo -e "a=True\nif a : print(1)")"
```

Here we're pre-processing `\n` before evaluating Python code.

That's super hacky! Don't write code like this.

Answer (score 9):

For a `python -c` oriented solution, and provided you use Bash shell, yes you can have a simple one-line syntax like in this example:

Suppose you would like to do something like this (very similar to your sample, including `except: pass` instruction):

```
python -c  "from __future__ import print_function\ntry: import numpy; print( numpy.get_include(), end='\n' )\nexcept:pass\n" OUTPUT_VARIABLE __numpy_path
```

This will *not* work and produce this *error*:

```
  File "<string>", line 1
    from __future__ import print_function\ntry: import numpy; print( numpy.get_include(), end='\n' )\nexcept:pass\n
                                                                                                                  ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character `
```

This is because the competition between Bash and Python *interpretation* of `\n` escape sequences. To solve the problem one can use the `$'string'` Bash syntax to force `\n` Bash interpretation *before* the Python one.

To make the example more challenging, I added a typical Python `end=..\n..` specification in the Python print call: at the end you will be able to get *both* `\n` interpretations from Bash and Python working together, each on its piece of text of concern. So that finally the proper solution is like this:

```
python -c  $'from __future__ import print_function\ntry:\n import numpy;\n print( numpy.get_include(), end="\\n" )\n print( "Hello" )\nexcept:pass\n' OUTPUT_VARIABLE __numpy_path
```

That leads to the proper clean output without an error:

```
/Softs/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include
Hello
```

Note: this should work as well with `exec`-oriented solutions, because the problem is still the same (Bash and Python interpreters competition).

Note 2: one could work around the problem by replacing some `\n` by some `;` but it will not work anytime (depending on Python constructs), while my solution allows to always "one-line" any piece of classic multi-line Python program.

Note 3: of course, when one-lining, one has always to take care of Python spaces and indentation, because in fact we are not strictly "one-lining" here, *but* doing a proper mixed-management of `\n` escape sequence between bash and Python. This is how we can deal with any piece of classic multi-line Python program. The solution sample illustrates this as well.

Answer (score 8):

**I recommend *not* doing this...**

What you are describing is *not* a comprehension.

[PEP 8 Style Guide for Python Code](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), which I *do* recommend, has this to say on compound statements:

> - Compound statements (multiple statements on the same line) are generally discouraged.
>
> Yes:
>
> ```
>       if foo == 'blah':
>           do_blah_thing()
>       do_one()
>       do_two()
>       do_three()
> ```
>
> Rather not:
>
> ```
>       if foo == 'blah': do_blah_thing()
>       do_one(); do_two(); do_three()
> ```

Here is a sample comprehension to make the distinction:

```
>>> [i for i in xrange(10) if i == 9]
[9]
```

Answer (score 3):

It’s actually possible ;-)

```
# Not PEP 8 compatible^
sam = ['Sam',]
try: print('hello', sam) if sam[0] != 'harry' else rais
except: pass
```

You can do very ugly stuff in Python like:

```
def o(s):return ''.join([chr(ord(n) + (13 if 'Z' < n < 'n' or 'N' > n else -13)) if n.isalpha() else n for n in s])
```

which is a function for [ROT13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13) and [Caesar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher) encryption in one line.

Comment: Is "`else rais`" correct?

Comment: Should it be `raise`? (After (`else`).)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe with "and" or "or".

After false, we need to write "or".

After true we need to write "and".

Like

```
n = 0

def returnsfalse():
    global n
    n = n + 1
    print("false %d" % (n))
    return False

def returnstrue():
    global n
    n = n + 1
    print("true %d" % (n))
    return True

n = 0
returnsfalse() or returnsfalse() or returnsfalse() or returnstrue() and returnsfalse()
```

Result:

```
false 1
false 2
false 3
true 4
false 5
```

Or maybe like

```
(returnsfalse() or true) and (returnstrue() or true) and ...
```

---

I got here by searching Google with "how to put multiple statments in one line Python". It does not answer the question directly, but maybe somebody else needs this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it without try and except, then there is the solution.

If you are trying to print 'hello' if 'harry' in a list
then the solution is:

```
'hello' if 'harry' in sam else ''
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a possible [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) compatible solution.

### Solution to `if, else`

```py
[print("i equals 9") for i in range(10) if i == 9]
```

Use a list generation instead of `if, else`.

I think this is probably a useful trick, which has already stated by [comment by ThomasH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167127/how-to-put-multiple-statements-in-one-line#comment108423224_6167353). So this is a serious solution.

### Solution to `try, except`

```py
print("hello", sam) \
    if "sam" in locals() \
    and hasattr(sam, "__getitem__") \
    and 0 < len(sam) \
    and sam[0] != "harry" \
    else None
```

Try to deal with how `expect` would behave by an in-line `if` statement. This line of code is specialized to deal with the existence of `sam[0]`, thus I couldn't resolve other general `try, except` cases.

This ***is*** one line of code (=w=). Though if written in exactly one-line, it could be too long to contradict [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) [E501](https://www.flake8rules.com/rules/E501.html). So this is *a solution for fun*.

- `"sam" in locals` checks if `sam` is a valid variable in the current environment;
- `hasattr(sam, "__getitem__")` checks if variable `sam` could be indexed by `sam[n]`;
- `0 < len(sam)` checks if `sam` have more than zero items;
- then check `sam[0] != "harry"`.
- **Warning**: This should work when `type(sam) == list`. Other cases were not tested. If you are sure that `sam` is a list, then the code would not be too lengthy:

  ```py
  print("hello", sam) if 0 < len(sam) and sam[0] != "harry" else None
  ```

### Additional Contents

As other answers (for example, [Johnsyweb stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6167200/7740992), multiple statements on one line is not preferred ([PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) [E701](https://www.flake8rules.com/rules/E701.html)). So, for any possible Pythonic (PEP 8) solution, the one-line code may have to avoid explicit `if, else` and `try, except`.

As [another comment by Thomash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167127/how-to-put-multiple-statements-in-one-line#comment7172789_6167353) stated, a better solution for `try, except` should using a wrapping function. This adds another lines of code; however, calling the function can not only check `sam` but also other variables:

```py
def check_harry(name):
    try:
        print("hello", name) if name[0] != "harry" else None
    except (NameError, TypeError, IndexError):
        pass

check_harry(uncle)
check_harry(sam)
```

This could be a more serious solution. Note that bare `except` is not recommended due to [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) [E722](https://www.flake8rules.com/rules/E722.html). Although this line of compulsive `except: pass` seems to be a waste of time (and I actually usually agree with that T_T), there lies some code style consideration.

Answer (score 1):

This solution might be complex, but working my [ubuntu](/questions/tagged/ubuntu)

one line of [python](/questions/tagged/python) script can

- [import](/questions/tagged/import) [yaml](/questions/tagged/yaml) and [sys](/questions/tagged/sys) lib
- [lambda-function](/questions/tagged/lambda-function) read yaml file by using first [sys.argv1](/questions/tagged/sys.argv1)
- get expected value from return [nested-dictionary](/questions/tagged/nested-dictionary) from lambda function by using [sys.argv2](/questions/tagged/sys.argv2) [sys.argv3](/questions/tagged/sys.argv3)
- print yaml_as_dict will load test_var as variable
- check test_var by `echo $test_var`

`

```
$
$ test_var=$(python3 -c $"import yaml,sys; yaml_as_dict=(lambda :yaml.safe_load(open(f'{sys.argv[1]}','r').read()))()[sys.argv[2]][sys.argv[3]]; print(yaml_as_dict)" <argv1> <argv2> <argv3>)
$
$ echo $test_var
$
```

[How to execute multiline python code from a bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75699840/16336393)

[How can I write multi-line code in the Terminal use python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75701538/16336393)

[How to define a bash variable from python EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75724494/16336393)

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing a lot of things, which makes it hard to answer your question. The short answer is: As far as I know, what you want to do is just not possible in Python - for good reason!

The longer answer is that you should make yourself more comfortable with Python, if you want to develop in Python. Comprehensions are not hard to read. You might not be used to reading them, but you have to get used to it if you want to be a Python developer. If there is a language that fits your needs better, choose that one. If you choose Python, be prepared to solve problems in a pythonic way. Of course you are free to fight against Python, But it will not be fun! ;-)

And if you would tell us what your real problem is, you might even get a pythonic answer. "Getting something in one line" us usually not a programming problem.

Comment: I love python! I was just demonstrating how i think comprehensions might be better structured but can't due to the colon which is the root of my problem/question ... I see by your answer that the multistatements seperated by colons such as try: if sam[0] != 'harry': print('hellp',  sam) are not possible ... is this correct? thanks ... im just using this for some debug purposes so I'm looking for small simple code that can be removed easy and doesn't take up lots of space lol

Comment: Yes, as far as I know it's not possible. But as somebody already statet: What you do is something different than comprehension. If you want to be able to remove the code easily, put it into a function. Regarding the "except: pass"-problem, think about an decorator which ignores exception or something like that. Again: Always try to describe your real problem, not the problem with the solution you have in mind already. ;-)

Comment: Why do people have to start their answer with uncalled for provocative statements like "you are mixing a lot of things"? Down vote if I can.

Comment: "Getting something in one line" us usually not a programming problem." —> but that is often a sysadmin problem, so the question is still relevant in this aspect.

Comment: @JohnJiang Does not feel out of line.  it's not a hostile-minded answer just a heads up type from someone trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [ThomasH's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167127/how-can-i-put-multiple-statements-in-one-line/6167353#6167353):

```
for i in range(4): print "i equals 3" if i==3 else None
```

Output:

```
None
None
None
i equals 3
```

I propose to update as:

```
for i in range(4): print("i equals 3") if i==3 else print('', end='')
```

Output:

```
i equals 3
```

Note, I am in Python 3 and had to use two print commands. `pass` after `else` won't work.

Comment: Related: *[Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/)*.

Answer (score -1):

```
sam = ['harry', 'john']

print('hello ' + sam[0] if sam[0] != 'harry' else '')
```

Answer (score -3):

Here is an example:

```
for i in range(80, 90): print(i, end=" ") if (i!=89) else print(i)
```

Output:

```
80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89
>>>
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., why does it print 89 when the condition is `i!=89`?