# declare multiple variables to same value

Tags: python

Using Python 3.3.3 and the pywin32 api.

I'm new to python and trying to simplify my script. I'm trying to assign a single value to multiple variables but it says

> Illegal expression for augmented assignment

```
import win32api
import win32con
import time

#makes sure your computer doesnt lock when idle for too long...
def move(x, y):
    for i in range(10):
        win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))

        if(i % 1 == 0): x, y += 10 #this is where it crashes
        if(i % 2 == 0): x, y -= 10

        time.sleep(5)

move(500, 500)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
if(i % 1 == 0): x+=10; y+=10
if(i % 2 == 0): x-=10; y-=10
```

Anyway be careful with i%1, it will always evaluate to 0 and therefore your first if will always execute. Maybe you wanted to write it like this to alternate the direction of cursor movement:

```
if(i % 2 == 1): x+=10; y+=10
if(i % 2 == 0): x-=10; y-=10
```

More reading: [How to put multiple  statements in one line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167127/how-to-put-multiple-statements-in-one-line)

Answer (score 2):

```
if(i % 1 == 0): x, y += 10 #this is where it crashes
if(i % 2 == 0): x, y -= 10
```

It's not possible to do this. When you **unpack** tuples in Python the number of variables on the left-hand-side **must equal** the no. of items in the tuple on the right-hand-side.

Answer (score 1):

You can chain together multiple plain assignments like:

```
a = b = 5
```

That doesn't work for augmented assignments like `+=` though. You'll have to write those separately.

```
if i % 1 == 0:
    x += 10
    y += 10
```

(Also, `if` doesn't require parentheses.)