# Why doesn't Python allow to put a for followed by an if on the same line?

Tags: python

Why is this code

```
for i in range(10):
    if i == 5: print i
```

valid while the compound statement (I know that [PEP 8 discourages](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) such coding style)

```
for i in range(10): if i == 5: print i
```

is not?

Comment: Try using a list comprehension

Comment: A list-comp is clearly incorrect for the above loop, since it would just build up a list of `None`s.

Comment: @roippi Not so. It would _only_ include values of 5.

Comment: @MatthewTrevor no.  He is only `print`ing, there is no list being made.  `[print(x) for x in range(10)]` is an abuse of list comprehension syntax and should be avoided.

Comment: @roippi Not if the comprehension feeds the for loop, which is what I took Daenyth's suggestion to mean.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to put multiple  statements in one line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167127/how-to-put-multiple-statements-in-one-line)

Comment: @devnull Thanks but I am interest in why Python doesn't allow `for i in range(10): if i == 5: print i`, not how to circumvent it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because python has strict rules about indentation being used to represent blocks of code and by putting an `for` followed by an `if`, you create ambiguous indentation interpretations and thus python does not allow it.

For python, you can put as many lines as you want after a `if` statement:

```
if 1==1: print 'Y'; print 'E'; print 'S'; print '!';
```

as long as they all have the same indentation level, i.e., no `if`, `while`, `for` as they introduce a deeper indentation level.

Hope that helps

Comment: This is documented in the `Python Language Reference` document under `Compound statements` (https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html): "A suite can be one or more semicolon-separated simple statements on the same line as the header, following the header’s colon, or it can be one or more indented statements on subsequent lines. Only the latter form of suite can contain nested compound statements [...]".

Answer (score 6):

The reason *why* you cannot is because [the language simply doesn't support it](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement):

```
for_stmt ::=  "for" target_list "in" expression_list ":" suite
              ["else" ":" suite]
```

It has been [suggested many times](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2014-March/027141.html) on the Python mailing lists, but has never really gained traction because it's already possible to do using existing mechanisms...

Such as a filtered generator expression:

```
for i in (i for i in range(10) if i == 5):
    ...
```

The advantage of this over the list comprehension is that it doesn't generate the entire list before iterating over it.

Comment: Including an `if` clause with a `for` statement is not really what the OP is asking about.  Disallowing multiple compound statements on the same line is a more general issue.

Answer (score 1):

using  list comprehension:

```
In [10]: [x for x in range(10) if x ==5][0]
Out[10]: 5
```

Comment: The OP was asking a "why" question, I don't see how your answer helps.

Comment: You don't see any relation?

Comment: I don't, the answer has to do with indentation rules, as explained by @sshashank124. As OP question stands, they were looking for an explanation of why certain code does not work, not a hacky 1-liner that does something similar. Your code is different, OP only intends to print an element, not create a list as you do.