# Python - Continuing from single line if statement

Tags: python, if-statement

For example
`if test == 1: x = 1; y = 1; z = 2`
Would it be possible to not have the `z = 2` within the if statement, while keeping it on the same line? Was just wondering if there was a way to do it, similar to how `\` continues a line or `;` ends one.

Comment: No, that is not possible.

Comment: Even if for a moment we believe that is possible but what will you gain? save one line by compromising readability?P.S that is not possible

Comment: It would be a reasonable request for one-liners to be run from the command line, but Python really isn't conducive to one-liners.

Comment: what do you mean? show some psudocode maybe? you can do `x,y,z = 1,1,2`

Comment: Some of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167127/how-to-put-multiple-statements-in-one-line) might help you if you need this for command line.

Answer (score 2):

Semi-colons only appear in one place in Python's grammar, as part of a *simple statement*:

```
simple_stmt: small_stmt (';' small_stmt)* [';'] NEWLINE
```

One place a simple statement occurs is in the definition of a *suite*:

```
suite: simple_stmt | NEWLINE INDENT stmt+ DEDENT
```

And a suite is the one and only thing that can comprise the body of an `if` statement:

```
if_stmt: 'if' test ':' suite ('elif' test ':' suite)* ['else' ':' suite]
```

From this, we can conclude that the only way to terminate the body of the `if` statement is with a newline or a `DEDENT` token. Since a `DEDENT` token can only occur with an `INDENT` token, which must follow a newline, you can see there is no way to put a statement that *follows* an `if` statement on the same line as the `if` itself.