# Assign, compare and use value in one line

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

Current code:

```
error = dict.get("error", None)
if error:
    print(error)
```

Is there a way to place it on one line, e.g.:

```
print(error) if (error = dict.get("error", None))
```

In C you can assign a value, then compare, then print it out on one line:

```
if (a = 5) printf("%d",a);
```

Comment: No, there isn't; your code is perfectly readable. Note that `None` is the default default value, so is redundant there.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a ternary `print("" if not d.get("error") else d["error"])` you can use [`dict.get(key,default)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) and [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) with a ternary telling `end=""` or `end="\n"` to avoid/use the newline after it:

```
d = {"error": "plenty"}  

print( d.get("error",""), end = "\n" if d.get("error","") else "")
```

This prints nothing (not even a newline due to `end=""`) if the key is not present.

See [Why dict.get(key) instead of dict[key]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041405/why-dict-getkey-instead-of-dictkey)

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3.8, you will be able to write

```
if error := dict.get("error", None):
    print(error)
```

Python does not have Perl-style statement modifiers, but since `print` is a function, you can write an expression statement like

```
print(error) if (error := dict.get("error", None)) else None
```

although I wouldn't recommend it. (Actually, I'm not entirely sure the assignment expressions defined by PEP-572 interact with a conditional expression. I haven't played with any reference implementations to test it, but I believe `error` will be in scope for the entire expression.)

---

A simple `if` statement like that, though, *can* be written on one line (although again, I wouldn't recommend it; PEP-8 explicitly frowns upon

```
if error := dict.get('error', None): print(error)
```

)

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167127/how-to-put-multiple-statements-in-one-line) you could possibly cram multiple expressions using a semicolon. Something like

```
error = my_dict.get("error", None); print(error) if error is not None else None
```

Should work, but I'm typing on my phone and can't test.

Comment: Just to agree with the comment above, cramming this into a one-liner feels like poor programming and should be avoided. Still, it is _possible_. Also, it's bad practice to overwrite the built in `dict` keyword with a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use inline `if else` provided by `python`.

```
print('error') if dict.get("error") else 0
```

That it! Hope it helps:)