# How do I write two statements to be executed on an if condition in a single line?

Tags: python

For a single statement, I can do this:

```
if 1: print("hello")
```

The output:

```
hello
```

But when I tried something like this:

```
if 1: print("hello") print("end")
```

I got an error:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    if 1: print("hello") print("end")
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why there is a syntax error? What is the right way to write multiple execution statement in single line with the `if` condition? I want to print the "hello" and "end" when the condition is satisfied.

I want a single-liner for the following statement:

```
if 1:
    print("hello")
    print("end")
```

Comment: What is print('end') doing after the hello? or, and, else??

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167127/how-to-put-multiple-statements-in-one-line

Comment: What do you gain by compressing code to one line?

Comment: @khelwood Its not always gain or loss matters. It is the approach. Actually I have few statements which were ruining my codes way or look. I am trying to debug the code and do not want that others should see the mess I performed. Ionly want that others should view the cleanest code that I ave written for the main purpose part from what I tried to debug.

Comment: `if 1: print("hello\nend")` ;)

Comment: @furas Yes you are absolutely right. But there statement is not only print but class functions. I was not able to mention as it might have become too broad and no one answers. Hence, I cut it short enough to make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if 1: print("hello") or print("end")
hello
end
```

More information on the use of `or`: [Strange use of "and" / "or" operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47007680/strange-use-of-and-or-operator/47007761#47007761)

---

```
if 1: print("hello"); print("end")
hello
end
```

Answer (score 4):

You should separate the two statements with `;`

```
if 1: print("hello"); print("end")
```

But don't do it. write it normally

```
if 1:
   print("hello")
   print("end")
```

The compact form is probably acceptable with one statement only, but anything more complex is harder to read

Comment: how does that work? does it create a tuple in-place?

Comment: @blue_note yest it creates tuple - you can also use list `[print("hello"), print("end")]`. Sometimes you can see this list in `lambda:[ ..., ... ]` - it lets you run many functions in lambda.

Comment: @furas: ok, but then it's kind of misleading. it creates an iterable just for the side-effect

Comment: @blue_note yes, it is misleading, use side-effect and it is not prefered. But it is good to know it when you see this in `lambda` or you want to create short one-liner to run it fast directly in command line :)

Answer (score 0):

```
print("hello" if 1 else 'end')
```

Check [this](https://www.pythoncentral.io/one-line-if-statement-in-python-ternary-conditional-operator/) for more details

Comment: This isn't the meaning of what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? This isn't quite clear from your described issue.

Comment: expected output is "hello\nend" from the two print statements.