# Fastest way to remove duplicates in a list without importing libraries and using sets

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I was trying to remove duplicates from a list using the following code:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,2,6,1,1,5,2]
res = []
[res.append(i) for i in a if i not in res]
```

But I would like to do this without defining the list I want as an empty list (i.e., omit the line `res = []`) like:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,2,6,1,1,5,2]

# Either:
res = [i for i in a if i not in res]

# Or:
[i for i in a if i not in 'this list'] # This list is not a string. I meant it as the list being comprehended.
```

I want to avoid library imports and `set()`.

Comment: I believe you cannot do that, use `set(a)` to remove duplicates, one-line and simple also. If order matters use a dictionary or an OrderedDict, depending on you Python's version, but this will be hacky.

Comment: I do not intent to use set or imported libraries :)

Comment: Not everything with lists is a natural candidate for a comprehension. Also, why use a quadratic algorithm?

Comment: @JoshuaVarghese Why?

Comment: This problem sounds artificial. There are many (and more efficient) ways of achieving what you want.

Comment: @rdas i would love to know those, if libraries aren't imported for its process

Comment: Using set do not import any library

Comment: You cannot refer to things that do not exist yet.

Comment: @DaniMesejo but set has disadvantages

Comment: Don't create useless meta tags, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing duplicates in lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-lists)

Comment: @Georgy that is not really the answer required! we need here the speed comparison

Comment: @JoshuaVarghese Fair enough, I will retract the flag and edit the title to make it more specific.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Python 3.6+, you can use `dict.fromkeys()`:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 6, 1, 1, 5, 2]
>>> list(dict.fromkeys(a))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5]
```

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys):

> Create a new dictionary with keys from iterable and values set to value.

If you are using a lower Python version, you will need to use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) to maintain order:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 6, 1, 1, 5, 2]
>>> list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(a))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5]
```

Answer (score 6):

I think this may work for you. It removes duplicates from the list while keeping the order.

```
newlist = [i for n,i in enumerate(L) if i not in L[:n]]
```

Comment: Very nice, using `enumerate` as the generator and check the list slice seen so far.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple benchmark with the proposed  solutions,

[image]

It shows that `dict.fromkeys` will perform the best.

```
from simple_benchmark import BenchmarkBuilder
import random


b = BenchmarkBuilder()

@b.add_function()
def AmitDavidson(a):
    return [i for n,i in enumerate(a) if i not in a[:n]]

@b.add_function()
def RoadRunner(a):
    return list(dict.fromkeys(a))

@b.add_function()
def DaniMesejo(a):
    return  list({k: '' for k in a})


@b.add_function()
def rdas(a):
    return  sorted(list(set(a)), key=lambda x: a.index(x))


@b.add_function()
def unwanted_set(a):
    return  list(set(a))


@b.add_arguments('List lenght')
def argument_provider():
    for exp in range(2, 18):
        size = 2**exp
        yield size, [random.randint(0, 10) for _ in range(size)]

r = b.run()
r.plot()
```

Comment: Ah nice. I was going to post something similar, but this is better. +1

Comment: this is awesomeness :) +1

Comment: stackoverflow should auto-create these graphs

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution using `set` that does preserve the order:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,2,6,1,1,5,2]
a_uniq = sorted(list(set(a)), key=lambda x: a.index(x))
print(a_uniq)
```

Comment: The main motivation for using `set` (beyond its concision) is to depulicate in sub-quadratic time but this use of `index` bumps it back up to quadratic.

Comment: So does the OPs comprehensions

Answer (score 2):

One-liner, comprehension, `O(n)`, that preserves order in Python 3.6+:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 6, 1, 1, 5, 2]

res = list({k: '' for k in a})
print(res)
```