# Moving values from one list to new list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement, methods

I am practicing coding and I would like some help.
Here is the prompt:
Take a list, say for example this one:

a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
and write a program that prints out all the elements of the list that are less than 5.

Extras:

1. Instead of printing the elements one by one make a new list that has all the elements less than 5 from this list in it and print out this new list.
2. Write this in one line of Python.
3. Ask the user for a number and return a list that contains only elements from the original list 'a' that are smaller than that number given by the user.

Here is my code:

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
number = int(input("Pick a number: "))
new_list = []
for item in a:
    if item < number:
        new_list.append(item)
    print(new_list)
```

The problem I keep running into is whenever I run it and use any number (In this case, I chose 5), I keep getting this result:

```
Pick a number: 5
[1]
[1, 1]
[1, 1, 2]
[1, 1, 2, 3]
[1, 1, 2, 3]
[1, 1, 2, 3]
[1, 1, 2, 3]
[1, 1, 2, 3]
[1, 1, 2, 3]
[1, 1, 2, 3]
[1, 1, 2, 3]
```

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Besides the earlier post to point out the mis-placed of `print` statement, you could achieve the same result as this one-liner:

```py
# one-liner

result = [x for x in a if x < number]

print(result)
```

Comment: Would it be more one-liner literally :)
`print([x for x in a if a < 5])`

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your print(new_list) statement outside of the for loop.

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
number = int(input("Pick a number: "))
new_list = []
for item in a:
    if item < number:
        new_list.append(item)
print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Although Daniel has already given the answer IMHO, but I'd like to add a little more, in case the 2nd requirement is still alive after the 3rd one.

```py
target = int(input("Pick a number: "));print([x for x in a if x < target])
```

`;` here is used to put some simple statements on one line.
For details, please refer [How to put multiple  statements in one line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167127/how-to-put-multiple-statements-in-one-line)