# How to execute multiple statement in a one line if loop?

Tags: python

I am trying to add a value to a variable and print it, in the same one line if loop.

First i tried to separate my 2 actions with a `,`:

```
test = 0
if True : test = 4, print(test)
> 0

print (test)
> (4, None)
```

I don't uderstand why my variable get the value 0 when printed from the if. Outside i get a list, like test value is `4, print(test)`

After i tried to use `and` between 2 actions :

```
test = ""
if True :  test = "hello" and print(test)
> 

print(test)
> None
```

I think my variable is trying to get the value : `test and print(toto)`

Do you know if and how can i do multiple actions in a single line if loop ?

(sorry for possible duplicate but i keep matching answers for multiple condition in one if loop)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to put multiple statements in one line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167127/how-to-put-multiple-statements-in-one-line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as of python 3.8 you can use walrus operator for both evaluating and assigning:

```
if True: print(test := "hello")
> hello
```

- you get 0, since `test = 4, print(test)` evaluates right hand side part as a tuple and assigns it to the `test` variable, thus it will assign to `test` 4 and the result of the print function, which is `None`
- `test = "hello" and print(test)` will once again evaluate the right side. you use `and` operator, which evaluates the first argument, which for not empty strings is `True`. it then proceeds to the next argument and it assigns its value to the variable. in your case it is the result of the print function, which is `None`