# python is it possible to import a library inline?

Tags: python, import

I am trying to write a one liner, but it requires the random library.

```
import random
print(random.choice(["Red team","Blue team"]))
```

is there any correct syntax that could say something like

```
print(__import__(random).choice(["Red team","Blue team"]))
```

or

```
with open('random') as r: print(r.choice(["Red team","Blue team"])))
```

Comment: While one-liners are useful, one has to keep the Zen in mind and the code must also be *easily understood*; which (in my opinion) this concept is not.  From that standpoint, I’d willingly go on a limb and say “No, there is not a *correct* syntax to accomplish this”. Stick with the standard import convention.

Comment: While I agree that readability is important and this should be avoided in virtually all situations, if you _really_ want to you can [use a semi-colon to separate statements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59122264/354577): `import random; print(random.choice(["Red team", "Blue team"]))`. (Note that there are no line breaks there. Any that you see are an artifact of SO's comment rendering.) `random` remains imported afterwards, though. This isn't like a context manager.

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!  I agree with the readability arguments. I didnt realize you can do this. 

I am not setting a pattern here, just sending a one line snippet people can use in an interpreter as a utility that has little to do with our mainstream product

Answer (score -1):

Even though it is discouraged, [importlib.import_module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) is the function you're looking for.

```py
import importlib
importlib.import_module("random").choice(["Red team","Blue team"])
```

Comment: I don't think this is what OP is asking for

Comment: So, instead of `import random`, you suggest `import importlib` in order to use it and import random?

Comment: I agree with @Chris. If importlib were part of standard python this would be exactly what I want, so its not technically wrong but unfortunately this robs peter to pay paul because you have to add the import statement to get impportlib making it still two lines