# How can I put multiple statements in one line in python?without using ; and exec

Tags: python, for-loop, lambda

I want to write this code in one line without using ; and exec

```
input_string = str(input())
array = []
for i in range(len(input_string)):
    if (ord(input_string[i]) - 97) % 2 == 0:
       array.append(input_string[i])
    else:
       array.append(input_string[i].upper())
array.sort(reverse=True)
answer = ' '.join(array)
print(answer)
```

and couldn't do that so i came up with 4 line like this

```
input_string = str(input())
array = []
for i in range(len(input_string)): array.append(input_string[i]) if (ord(input_string[i]) -97) % 2 == 0 else array.append(input_string[i].upper())
print(' '.join(sorted(array,reverse=True)))
```

please help me to write this code in one line. thank you all in advance.

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6167353/4713169

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I put multiple statements in one line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167127/how-can-i-put-multiple-statements-in-one-line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done.

```
print(' '.join(sorted([letter if (ord(letter) -97) % 2 == 0 else letter.upper() for letter in str(input())],reverse=True)))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).